Excel xlsx parse Picture In-Cell MetaData
In modern Excel you may place pictures in cells.
I am writing a Python tool which reads and parses this data from xlsx files.
When a cell only contains a direct reference to an image, it appears simple to parse worksheet cell 'vm' attributes and match to the corresponding image in xl/media:
<c r="A1" t="e" vm="1">
    <v>#VALUE!</v>
</c>

The above example '1' correctly points to the expected image file xl/media/image1.png
However, when a cell image is from the result of a formula, the 'vm' attribute starts returning numbers that are not as I expect. They are larger than the total number of images in xl/media:
<c r="A2" t="e" vm="6">
    <f>A1</f>
    <v>#VALUE!</v>
</c>

In the above example A2 points to A1. A1 shows image1.png so '1' is expected. There are only 4 images in the workbook so 6 is also larger than expected.
What is happening here, is my understanding correct? Is there any simple way I can figure that out that the '6' actually means '1'?
